# What types of undead exist in Z-Corps?

Tags: campaign-settings, undead, d6-system

Recently I stumbled over the existence of [Z-Corps](http://aka-games.com/website/?page_id=883), a French zombie RPG based on the D6 system. As intriguing as it is... it is only available in French and Spanish at this time and the English translation is still in progress.

What type of undead exist in the Z-Corps game universe? I assume at least zombies, so what type of zombies exist: only the basic walker, or are there different ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what I can remember...

- Basic zombies: vulnerable to Agent Grey, a gas which slows zombies
- Resilient zombies: invulnerable to Agent Grey, but otherwise same as above
- "Fat" zombies: kinda like the boomer from *Left 4 Dead*
- All kind of animals (though mainly dogs)
- "Telepathic" zombies, which have some limited control over other zombies (go there, attack this guy, etc.)

Those were all the kinds of zombies described in the core book, I think.

In addition, each zombie has a "generation" depending on how far they are from Patient Zero, giving them more or less strength.